# How do I deploy a Docker app without publishing it?

Tags: windows, docker

How do I deploy a Docker app without publishing it to their hub? I don't want to create a username and password on their service (they just want to trap flies in their ecosystem), and I don't think I will use the *swarm* part of Docker. Besides that, it sounds very insecure to publish your closed-source code on a public repository! However I want to see how it works and want to learn the *stack* part, which depends on the *swarm* part. I followed their tutorial, but the app only deployed on the local default master node.

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#deploy-the-app-on-the-swarm-manager

`docker-composer.yml`

```
...
# replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
image: friendlyhello
```

3 machines/nodes with 1 master node

```
C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.03.1-ce
myvm1     -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v18.03.1-ce
myvm2     -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376           v18.03.1-ce
```

The app is deployed with 6 instances.

```
C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                  PORTS
uvsxf1q7brhb        getstartedlab_web   replicated          6/6                 friendlyhello:latest   *:80->80/tcp
```

However the app only fell onto the default master node and none of the swarm nodes.

```
C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker service ps getstartedlab_web
ID                  NAME                      IMAGE                  NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                ERROR
        PORTS
6jh1ua0wjyzi        getstartedlab_web.1       friendlyhello:latest   default             Running             Running about an hour ago

to14hu7g3rhz         \_ getstartedlab_web.1   friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
ek91tcdj61nv         \_ getstartedlab_web.1   friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
jwdvuf89a640         \_ getstartedlab_web.1   friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
xrp0rim67ipi        getstartedlab_web.2       friendlyhello:latest   default             Running             Running about an hour ago

tp008eoj2mpk        getstartedlab_web.3       friendlyhello:latest   default             Running             Running about an hour ago

w6wyk3nj53zv         \_ getstartedlab_web.3   friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
7ts6aqianz7l         \_ getstartedlab_web.3   friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
gjt1qks57rud         \_ getstartedlab_web.3   friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
o05u4qwt12vq        getstartedlab_web.4       friendlyhello:latest   default             Running             Running about an hour ago

ifzmmy8ru443         \_ getstartedlab_web.4   friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
jnxn8gs3bte3         \_ getstartedlab_web.4   friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
xsooht9gpf01         \_ getstartedlab_web.4   friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
v23mjl8n3yyd        getstartedlab_web.5       friendlyhello:latest   default             Running             Running about an hour ago

meocennltdph        getstartedlab_web.6       friendlyhello:latest   default             Running             Running about an hour ago

3t78bpswwuyw         \_ getstartedlab_web.6   friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
y3ih3md932qo         \_ getstartedlab_web.6   friendlyhello:latest   myvm2               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
sqsngkq1440a         \_ getstartedlab_web.6   friendlyhello:latest   myvm1               Shutdown            Rejected about an hour ago   "No such image: friendlyhello:"
```

Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302, Windows 8.1

---

I tried to follow

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/README.md#quick-start
https://docs.docker.com/registry/#basic-commands
https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/

I set this line in `docker-compose.yml`

```
image: 192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2
```

But after I ran `docker stack deploy` it still failed!

```
C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
Creating network getstartedlab_webnet
Creating service getstartedlab_web

C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                   PORTS
jjr7cuqy2i54        getstartedlab_web   replicated          0/6                 192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2   *:80->80/tcp

C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker service ps getstartedlab_web
ID                  NAME                      IMAGE                                   NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR
                      PORTS
bsx3slkj8pbr        getstartedlab_web.1       192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2   myvm1               Ready               Rejected 3 seconds ago    "No such image: 192.168.99.100"
cusqg0p35cwp         \_ getstartedlab_web.1   192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2   default             Shutdown            Rejected 8 seconds ago    "No such image: 192.168.99.100"
...
```

The image is in 'localhost' but not 192.168.99.100.

```
C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker pull localhost:5000/get-started:part2
part2: Pulling from get-started
Digest: sha256:fedc2e7c01a45dab371cf4e01b7f8854482b33564c52d2c725f52f787f91dbcb
Status: Image is up to date for localhost:5000/get-started:part2

C:\Temp\docker-tutorial>docker pull 192.168.99.100:5000/get-started:part2
Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

`localhost:5000` refuses to connect in the browser. I also tried `localhost:5000/get-started:part2` as the image name, but that also failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your own docker container registry or use private container registries from many cloud-providers with your custom auth. Few options:

- **AWS ECR / Amazon Elastic Container Registry**: https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/
- **Azure Container Registry**: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/
- **Codefresh private docker registries**: https://codefresh.io/
- **Artifactory**: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Registry

If you want to have complete control, you can alternatively host your own `Docker Registry` as well:

- https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/README.md
- https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/

Once you setup your registry you can just simply authenticate with `docker login` and then manage your images with `docker push/pull` as usual.

Comment: Wow so you have to have a Registry server running and there's no way to have `docker stack deploy` just copy the app with `rsync` or `scp`? This might be overkill for a tutorial, or for many real  apps. I have no idea how to point Docker to my own registry.

Comment: I updated the question with some extra information. Using your own registry is not working.